# On uint64 to double conversion: Why is the code simpler after a shift right by 1?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, sse, floating-point-conversion

Why is `AsDouble1` much more straightforward than `AsDouble0`?

```
// AsDouble0(unsigned long):                          # @AsDouble0(unsigned long)
//         movq    xmm1, rdi
//         punpckldq       xmm1, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm1 = xmm1[0],mem[0],xmm1[1],mem[1]
//         subpd   xmm1, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1]
//         movapd  xmm0, xmm1
//         unpckhpd        xmm0, xmm1                      # xmm0 = xmm0[1],xmm1[1]
//         addsd   xmm0, xmm1
//         addsd   xmm0, xmm0
//         ret
double AsDouble0(uint64_t x) { return x * 2.0; }

// AsDouble1(unsigned long):                          # @AsDouble1(unsigned long)
//         shr     rdi
//         cvtsi2sd        xmm0, rdi
//         addsd   xmm0, xmm0
//         ret
double AsDouble1(uint64_t x) { return (x >> 1) * 2.0; }
```

Code available at: https://godbolt.org/z/dKc6Pe6M1

Comment: FYI, you don't need to include a `main()` on Godbolt if you just want to look at the asm.  Also semi-related [Are there unsigned equivalents of the x87 FILD and SSE CVTSI2SD instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233028) except that's the reverse direction.  [How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41144668) covers packed conversions.

Comment: [What's So Difficult About \`uint64\_t\`? (Conversion Assembly From \`float\`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685576) is specifically about compiler-generated code for `(uint64_t)float`.

Comment: @PeterCordes re. main(), is an artifact of my other tests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

x86 has an instruction to convert between **signed** integers and floats. Unsigned integer conversion is (I think) supported by AVX512, which most compilers don't assume by default. If you shift right a `uint64_t` once, the sign bit is gone, so you can interpret it as a signed integer and have the same result.

Comment: Correct, [`vcvtsd2usi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtsd2usi) is new with AVX-512, along with packed conversions to unsigned 32 and 64-bit integers.  (Packed conversion to 64-bit was also new).

Comment: @Peter Wouldn't it be `vcvtusi2sd` to convert *from* an unsinged int to a double? But I guess we all know what you mean. :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole: Oops, yes, got the direction backwards, including in my comments under the question.

Answer (score 6):

The `cvtsi2sd` instruction takes, as its source operand, a ***signed*** integer (either 32- or 64-bits wide). However, your functions take ***unsigned*** arguments.

Thus, in the first case, the compiler cannot directly use the `cvtsi2sd` instruction, because the value in the given argument may not be representable as a same-size signed integer – so it generates code that does the conversion to `double` the "long way" (but safely).

However, in your second function, the initial right shift by one bit **guarantees** that the sign bit will be clear; thus, the resultant value will be identical, whether it is interpreted as signed or unsigned … so the compiler can safely use that (modified) value as the source for the `cvtsi2sd` operation.